# SQL Compact 4 - Full-text search?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

Will SQL 4 have full-text search capabilities? Can't find anything in blogs (including Scott Gu). Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not mentioned on the [SQL Compact team blog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sqlservercompact/introducing-sql-server-compact-4-0-the-next-gen-embedded-database-from-microsoft), so I'd say "no".